# Hovering over one element change style background color opacity of another element

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```css
        body  {
            background-color: darkgray;
            font-size: 2em;
         }

        div  {
            margin: 2em;
        }

        #outer  {
            background-color: purple;
            border: 2px solid transparent;
        }

        #outer:hover  {
            cursor: pointer;
            opacity: 40%;
            border: 2px solid yellow;
        }

        #first:hover  {
            color: red;
            font-weight: bold;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        #first:hover #outer  {
            background-color: green;
            opacity: 100%;
        }
```

```html
    <div id="outer">
        Outer

        <div id="first">
            First
        </div>
    </div>
```

It shows this:

[image]

When I hover over `#outer` it shows this:

[image]

When I hover over `#first` it shows this:

[image]

I'd like it to make the `#outer` background green and its opacity 100%, when the `#first` is hovered over.

However, it doesn't happen - when `#first` is hovered, the `#outer` background stays purple and its opacity stays 40%. How do I fix it?

EDIT:

I'm OK with updating all elements (for instance if there are more `outer` elements than one). And I don't want to use Javascript!

Comment: I updated the tags to add javascript as the solution for this will be javascript as you need to select the parent of the hovered element.

Comment: @imvain2 I don't care about the parent element. I'm OK with updating a style of all `#outer` elements. I don't want to use JS

Comment: the problem is you don't care about the parent element, but outer is the parent element. And CSS works in one direction and that is down, not up. So it goes down through the children, not reversing back up the DOM. You can try the :has in this answer but I don't think it will work for your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector